# How to copy a database table after a mysqldump

Tags: mysql

I have a mysqldump of all my databases from all projects created like this:

mysqldump -u username -h localhost --all-databases | gzip -9  > alldb.sql.gz

I now want to copy a specific database of a specific project (project1) of this alldb.sql file (which I have already gunzipped). I need to copy the project1_production database into the anotherproject_development database of an application I'm currently developing.

What is the easiest way to copy (and overwrite if entries already exist) the project1_production database of the alldb.sql file into the anotherproject_development database of my application I'm currently developing?

Comment: You use Crontab for `MYSQLDUMP` ?

Comment: The easiest way? It's to have separate dumps.

Comment: Yes I use Crontab. I can go for seperate dumps in the future, but since I run multiple applications it would be much easier for me to keep all databases in one file like I have done now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
mysql -D mydatabase -o < dump.sql
```

A so thread is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2342356/import-single-database-from-all-databases-dump)

Comment: Thanks, but I need to import the project1_production database of teh alldb.sql file into the project1_development database of my application. So it's a little bit trickier I guess...

Comment: restore and just rename. :)