# mysql restore of single database from mysqldump

Tags: mysql

I am trying to restore a single database from a MYSQL dump which contains many databases.

I am trying the query in ubuntu command prompt:

```
mysql -u root -p --one-database pmadb < localhost.sql
```

But mysql still trying to create other database in the dump file like:

**ERROR 1007 (HY000) at line 22: Can't create database 'c0roundcube'; database exists**

Can't understand what I am doing wrong here.
Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2342356/import-single-database-from-all-databases-dump

Comment: @DigitalChris I have seen that link as well. Can't make out the solution. where to run that command - mysql -D mydatabase -o < dump.sql . Moreover it says that the Database should be in use - how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You run this at the command line just like you did your statement.

```
mysql -u root -p -D pmadb -o < localhost.sql
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. I was already using that command, but my error was, I created a db as pma instead of phpmyadmin. Anyway thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Your MySQL instance must already have a database named `c0roundcube`, and your MySQL dump includes a [`CREATE DATABASE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-database.html) command, which is preventing you from importing the file.

If you're looking to start fresh, you can either [`DROP DATABASE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/drop-database.html) on the existing database, *which will delete it in its entirety (including all tables)*.

Or you can remove the `CREATE_DATABASE` commands from your SQL dump, which may work depending on whether your database is already prepopulated with the same tables. (If you've already removed the tables from this database, this method will work fine, but if you already have the tables, you're going to run into the same issue with `CREATE TABLE` failing since the tables with the same name exist.)